# Send data via Bluetooth using Action_Send intent

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is that possible to send data via Bluetooth to specific device (knowing the mac Address) using Action_Send ? If yes then please give any link or code . Thank you .

Comment: Try searching and then asking a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ACTION_CHOOSER intent, but that will provide the user a list of apps that can be used to share data, among which you'll see Bluetooth as well.

check this blog
http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent